# mysql SELECT column value dependent on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
ID | Type   | woof | meow
1  |  dog   |  1   |  0
2  |  cat   |  1   |  1
3  |  dog   |  0   |  0
4  |  cat   |  0   |  1
```

I want to `SELECT DISTINCT id, type WHERE` if type=dog then woof=1, and if type=cat then meow=1. So my expect output would consist of row 1,2 and 4.

How can I do this? I am assuming with some sort of fancy IF or CASE statement but I couldn't easily figure it out from mysql's documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use AND and OR:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, type 
FROM yourtable
WHERE (type='dog' AND woof=1) OR (type='cat' AND meow=1)
```

Note also that if your `id` field is unique (and I'm guessing that it is) then the DISTINCT is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 4):

Just use simple boolean algebra:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, type
FROM table
WHERE
  (type = 'dog' AND woof = 1) OR
  (type = 'cat' AND meow = 1)
```